# How to make dropdown menus work using popperjs in Bootstrap 5

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, popper.js, bootstrap-5

I'm currently trying to make dropdown menus work in Bootstrap 5. I read this functionality requires Popper.js, but I don’t know how to include it (Laravel project using Laravel mix) properly.

I’ve tried the following.

```
window.Popper = require(“@popperjs/core”)

import { createPopper } from '@popperjs/core'

import '@popperjs/core'
```

None of this seems to enable the Bootstrap dropdown functionality that I want! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try with the `bootstrap.js` file?

```js
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

require('bootstrap');
```

this file is used when you install [laravel ui](https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/3.x/src/Presets/bootstrap-stubs/bootstrap.js)

Answer (score 2):

The following will work, Popper.js is deprecated. Install version 2...

```
npm i @popperjs/core
```

Then in your bootstrap.js...

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('@popperjs/core');
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {
}
```

Finally, run `npm run dev` and include the following in your layout...

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

Comment: `.default` seems to be undefined. Just `window.Popper = require('@popperjs/core')` seems to be it.